# Error when trying to copy a file using shutil

Tags: python, shutil

Im trying to copy a file from one location to the other. Therefore I do:

```
import shutil
import os
source = os.listdir("C:/Users/Marc/Dropbox/PROJECTEN/Lopend/PianoKing/AssignScores/Final/")
destination = "C:/Users/Marc/Dropbox/PROJECTEN/Lopend/PianoKing/AssignScores/Final/test"

for files in source:
 if files.endswith(".txt"):
  print(files)
  shutil.copy(files,destination)
```

This shows me that there is a location but the files are not copied. I get the following error:

```
 File "C:/Users/Marc/contexta-misc-python-scripts/kaldi_corpus/recognize_zip_code.py", line 9, in <module>
 shutil.copy(files,destination)
 File "C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 119, in copy
 copyfile(src, dst)
 File "C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda2\lib\shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
 with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
 IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '1.txt'
```

Any thoughts on what is triggering this error?

Comment: Add source dir to a path: `shutil.copy(os.path.join(source,files),destination)`

Comment: @Serenity, gives me this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Marc/contexta-misc-python-scripts/kaldi_corpus/recognize_zip_code.py", line 16, in <module>
    shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, files), destination)
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 65, in join
    result_drive, result_path = splitdrive(path)
  File "C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda2\lib\ntpath.py", line 116, in splitdrive
    normp = p.replace(altsep, sep)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: OK, no other suggestion.